# Can firebase setup password authentication if user already has passwordless sign on?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase in my frontend JS project (firebase web). The current authentication I have setup is using the passwordless (email link) authentication for users. Is it possible to also set up password sign on for an already existing user with passwordless sign on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that you can just call:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePassword()
```

to set a password for a user that already has passwordless sign on set up.

Comment: I don't suppose you also found a way to identify any users that had already authenticated  via passwordless (email link) authentication? I need to migrate my users from passwordless to passworded email login (as I have to drop support for passwordless login), but with the limited Firebase APIs, I'm unsure how to identify which users have been migrated already and which ones still need to be migrated.

Comment: The user object has an object that lists the providers/sign in methods they have, you can check if that includes the password method. Some details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information

Comment: Thanks, checking it out now... `currentUser.providerInfo` returns an array of `UserInfo`, each of which according to the docs only contains an `email` field but no `password` field. It does also contain a `providerId` field, but only specifies that to be of type `string`. They don't document what the string can resolve to, but from what I've heard, it may only say "Firebase" (though I could be recalling incorrectly). Could you possibly provide a code snippet to detail how exactly you did it?

Comment: Separate from my question of how to identify accounts that need migrating, but I've found a section in the Firebase docs, [the API reference for `updatePassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-user#updatepasswordasync), that confirms that your `updatePassword()` approach is the correct way to go about upgrading passwordless users to passworded email auth. It says "For an account linked to an Identity Provider (IDP) with no password, this will result in the account becoming an email/password-based account while maintaining the IDP link."

Comment: Update @TheRyan722: I've now checked the `currentUser.providerData` (I accidentally wrote `currentUser.providerInfo` before) and sadly each `userInfo` element has the same value for `providerId` (`"password"`), regardless of whether the user authenticated with passwordless or passworded sign-in.

Comment: Update 2: I see what you mean now. [`auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(currentUser.email)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#differentiating_emailpassword_from_email_link) returns a Promise for an array of sign-in methods i.e. `["password"]` or `["emailLink"]`. More information on that documentation page. Looks like I'll be able to proceed now!

Comment: @JamieBirch Correct, that is what I use to check the provider methods. I forgot what the function was since it's been a while since I've had to look at it